# Azure Data factory pipeline: How to display Custom Activity Progress in azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a time consuming custom activity running in a Azure data factory pipeline.
It copies files from Blob to FTP server recursively.

The entire activity take 3-4 hours based on the number of files in the folder.
But when I am running the pipeline, it shows in progress 0%.

How update pipeline progress from custom activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I doubt you will be able to. The services are very discounted from each other.

You might be better off writing out to the Azure generic activity log and monitoring directly from the custom activity method. This is an assumption though.

Hope this helps.